# What is an alternative for the reference using.System.Data.Oledb

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, oledb

What is an alternative for the reference `using.System.Data.Oledb` ?
This reference is not supported in device application form in visual studio 2013.

I want to develop a Windows embedded compact form in vs 2013. It doesn't support the Oledb reference and hence is giving me error for using the `datagridview.datamember.`

**UPDATE**

I am using SQLite database.

Comment: Welcome! You have to tell us what database you are using. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need OleDb because 1) it is too old and 2) not on mobile device. On a Windows embedded platform, you should avoid using a local database if possible or connect to a remote database. To connect to local SQL Server (embedded version) you should use the namespace such as "System.Data.SqlClient". To connect to remote database, build a middle layer which exposes web services.

Comment: Okk. Thanku so much .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, but include `System.Data`

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

Comment: Thanku for ur reply. I tried the same reference. System.data.Oledb. it is not supported

Comment: This reference is not present in my reference assemblies of windows embedded compact. So I cannot include it in my project

Comment: Hope this helps:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47f5c2b1-8496-4af0-9784-2868442e6539/the-type-or-namespace-name-oledb-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-systemdataare-you-missing-an?forum=adodotnetdataproviders
Please Read until the End of the page.

Comment: I am using SQLite database.

Comment: I have to deploy my project onto another device so my project type is output project